# Extremely slow ResultSet next() performance

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to get some results from an oracle db and then insert these rows into another oracle db with using jdbc batch. But while loop with `resultset.next()` is very slow.

The select query includes rowNum and some table joins. In addition, there are 90+ columns in it. I don't have any chances to improve query it's unreachable. Still, I supposed this is not enough challenging which clarifies slowness. This is not normal and I could not find any solution.

Here is my code. When I commented out all code
inside `while` but not `counter++`, slowness remains. So I am pretty sure about source of issue is `sdResult.next()`. You can also find performance results below.

```
    try {
            ResultSet sdResult = sdbConnInstance.executeQuery(SOURCE_DB_QUERY1.toString());
            logger.info("bulkInsert started at: " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> columnMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> bulkList = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>();
            operationCleaned = true;
            int counter = 0;
            int countToBulkInsert = 0;
            while(sdResult.next()) {                                
                operationCleaned = false;
                counter++;
                for (int i = 0; i < SOURCE_DB_COLUMNS1_ARRAY.length; i++) {
                        String column = SOURCE_DB_COLUMNS1_ARRAY[i];
                        try {
                                columnMap.put(column, sdResult.getString(column));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                columnMap.put(column, null);
                        }

                }
                bulkList.add(columnMap);
                columnMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
                if (countToBulkInsert == BULK_INSERT_COUNT) {
                        tdbConnInstance.insertWithBatch(INSERT_QUERY_TEMPLATE.toString(), bulkList);
                        lEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        logger.info(countToBulkInsert + " rows are inserted in " + (lEndTime - lStartTime) + " ms. Total count=" + counter + ". New query is building...");
                        lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        countToBulkInsert = 0;
                        bulkList = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>();
                        operationCleaned = true;
                }
            }
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Failed to insert!");
   }
```

**If I don't use setFetchSize():**

INFO: 100 rows are inserted in 61804 ms. Total count=100. New query is building...

INFO: 100 rows are inserted in 94150 ms. Total count=200. New query is building...

INFO: 100 rows are inserted in 61148 ms. Total count=300. New query is building...

**If I use setFetchSize(100) with PreparedStatement:**

INFO: 100 rows are inserted in 62 ms. Total count=100. New query is building...

INFO: 100 rows are inserted in 60367 ms. Total count=200. New query is building...

INFO: 100 rows are inserted in 64540 ms. Total count=300. New query is building...

Comment: How long does it take if you use a SQL client to read the same data ?

Comment: I am using sql developer and it takes ~70 sec.

Comment: Then it's the same as you're getting in Java, problem is with the Database server. Java can't do anything for that.

Comment: No, i mean retrieving all data with select query took 70 sec. Select query returns over 80K rows. But resultset.next cursor's move took ~60 sec for each of only 100 rows. DB insert, update operations or data structure operations are much much faster than that.

Comment: Have you verified that all 80K rows were fetched ? Sometimes SQL clients have an internal limit on the number of rows they fetch by default.

Comment: What's the fetchsize.  If it's the default, it may be very small thus requiring another trip to the database for every 10 rows

Comment: When i run the select query with sql array fetch size of 500 (which is allowed max), the query took ~320 sec on sql developer. So I am convinced that query has a bad performance. Java can't do anything. I supposed that if engine reaches the row of code which is after the resultSet row, the resulset obj has all the data. This is what i was wrong. I think I should learn much more about how resultset works. Thanks for your help @11thdimension and David

Comment: @kahramani you can use `Explain Plan` feature from oracle to analyze your query performance and the bottle neck that it has. Chek this link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i17492

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 Resultset sdResult = sdbConnInstance.executeQuery(SOURCE_DB_QUERY1.toString());
sdResult.setFetchSize(100);
```

it will be fast

change 100 to your row size.